# Checkbox vs Radiobox

Tags: html

I have to display a form and the users must decide on selecting just one or no option.

A Checkbox will work but it's not mutually exclusive.
A RadioBox will work but I will have to add an extra value with None.

What is the best practice for this ?

Update

Just to be clear an admin must decide if a user can edit or view an article.
I would like a list of checkboxes with Edit(includes View) and View.

If I use 2 checkboxes then be can select both of them and that's not ok, cause Edit would be enought.
If I use 2 radioboxes they will be excluded but I need an extra one for none.
If I use a list that's not pretty.

Comment: Duplicate? I saw exactly the same question yesterday.

Comment: @Daniel - can you post a link to this duplicate?

Comment: if you only have one option, why do you need mutual exclusivity?

Comment: @Oded: can't find it anymore... maybe it was a dream.

Comment: @Daniel - could have been deleted in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Radio with the extra option, select is hideous in terms of usability.

Comment: The question was asking whether you should have a single checkbox, or two radio buttons (one for 'yes' and one for 'no')

Comment: @nickf: looks like he want the option to check one of many answers or no answer at all, so the need to an extra option "None".

Answer (score 3):

If you need to have a mutually exclusive choice, use a regular `select` or a list of radio buttons (with the extra option).

If it is a set of options (not mutually exclusive), use a multi select or checkboxes.

These are standard UI idioms and people are used to them - it is good practice to stick to them.

---

Update:

Since you are talking about a *single* choice (yes/no), a single checkbox is the right choice.

Answer (score 2):

Although, when allowing user to make only one selection, a Radio button is the best choice. But as you are giving user only one option, you should use a Check Box. It will allow user to deselect if he/she decided to do it after selection which he/she will not be able to do in case of a Radio button.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are willing to invest time into making a checkbox list mutually exclusive (you can google for some options using DHTML) or not.
In my opinion, end-users are more likely to prefer check-boxes rather than radio-buttons. Even more, if they are not the standard check-boxes (using images for example) they are "more pleasing to the eye".

If you don't care for the "pleasing of the eyes" thing, you should go with radio-buttons.

Comment: This is the functionality i want but I don't want to invest in implementing this. So what is the next best alternative.

Comment: Here's a nice idea : http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t109936-any-way-to-make-a-checkboxlist-behave-like-a-radiobutton.html